# I'm confused about the basics of pointers/references

Tags: java, android

Given this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
a++;
```

Is b = 10 or 11? if 10, then why does this happen (I'm using Android as an example):

```
TextView x = new TextView();
TextView y = x;
x.setText("abcde");
```

which leads to y's text being also set to "abcde", doesn't it?

EDIT:

What if I use 'Integer' instead of 'int'? Will b = 11?

Comment: There are no pointers in `Java` !

Comment: Lol. What's the difference bet. it and reference (sorry for my ignorance :D)?

Comment: A good way to see what's going on is to debug through the code and see what happens.

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara surely there are pointers in Java. You just cannot manipulate them as freekly like e. g. in C. But an object reference is nothing else than a pointer. ;-)

Comment: Java uses reference types, if an object is 'complex' i.e. not a primitive String etc, the equals operator `=` on these types stores a reference. On primitives, i.e. int, boolean etc, the values are copied.  So b is equal to 10.

Comment: @BjörnKautler It creates more confusion to use the term pointers in Java, hence I avoid to use it for Java

Comment: You didn't avoid it, you stated there are none and that is wrong. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

An `int` is a primitive, so `a` and `b` don't refer to an object, they just hold a value. Therefore the assignment `int b = a;` copies the original value of `a` to `b` and `a++` only modifies `a`.

With reference types, the behavior is different, as shown in your `TextView` snippet. `x` and `y` refer to the same `TextView` instance (object), so `x.setText("abcde")` modifies the single instance referred by both.

Comment: Not really. In the second example he also just copies the original value of `x` to `y`. But the value is the reference to the `TextView` object and thus they point to the same object. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to go back to basics.

Things work differently for primitives and objects in Java.

For instance, for code below, `a` and `b` are different variables and have their individual values.

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
a++;
```

So when you do `a++` it only affects value for `a` and not `b` because they are primitives and they have separate individual values.

But for this code

```
TextView x = new TextView();
TextView y = x;
x.setText("abcde");
```

Both `x` and `y` are different variables, but **they both are referring to the same object in memory**.

So when you change the value using one referrer, it will get changed on the actual object in memory, and hence you get the new value when you access it, although this time using a different variable referring to the same object in memory.

Comment: What if I use Integer instead of int then?

Comment: `Integer` is basically a wrapper class for primitive type `int`, so it will behave the same as for `int`. See some documentation on Java wrapper classes and you will get the idea.

Comment: No difference. As you can see in my answer `a++` is just short for `a = a + 1`. So in this situation Integer will be autounboxed to int, then addition done and autoboxed to Integer again for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `a++` is the short form of `a = a + 1` so you assign a new value to `a` which is the result of adding `1` to `a`. But in the second example you call a method on the object that is referenced by both `x` and `y`, so you modify the object.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, Memory is created for that object. And object y is pointing to object x. So Object x and object y are accessing same memory. Whenever we change any property of object x, it's get stored in that memory location. As object y also pointing to same memory location, values gets reflected to properties of object y as well.

In your first case, we are just assigning values to a variable, we are not assigning a separate memory block for that variable.

Answer (score 0):

> What if I use 'Integer' instead of 'int'? Will b = 11?

**Answer**: Integer is a wrapper class, when we want to use Objects instead of primitive data types we use wrapper classes. and "b" will be same in both cases.
Wrapper classes provides mechanism for converting primitive types into objects and objects into primitive types (boxing and un-boxing)

Other part is explained well by other guys so am not adding anything for it.

Answer (score 0):

With the Integer question, Integer in Java is immutable. You will have to make a new Integer to increment. Therefore, it won't work.

The other part is already answered.